# Is it possible to download and unzip in parallel?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, zip, dotnetzip

I have some large zip files that I'm downloading and then unzipping in my program. Performance is important, and one direction I started thinking about was whether it was possible to start the download and then begin unzipping the data as it arrives, instead of waiting for the download to complete and then start unzipping. Is this possible? From what I understand of DEFLATE, it should be theoretically possible right?

I'm currently using DotNetZip as my zip library, but it refuses to act on a non-seekable stream.

Code would be something like this:

```
// HTTP Get the application from the server
var request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";

Directory.CreateDirectory(localPath);
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    // Unzip being some function which will start unzipping and
    // return when unzipping is done
    return Unzip(input, localPath);
}
```

Comment: So you want to read a bunch of bytes from a download stream, then uncompress them in parallel while downloading more data?

Comment: Yes, that's essentially the gist of it. DEFLATE works on each block at a time, so it seems like as long as I grab some blocks of data the unzip should be able to get started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I started thinking about was whether it was possible to start the download and then begin unzipping the data as it arrives, instead of waiting for the download to complete and then start unzipping. Is this possible?

If you want to start unzipping whilst the response body is still downloading, you can't *really* do this.

In a ZIP file, the Central Directory Record, which contains the list of files in the ZIP file, is located at the very end of the ZIP file. It will be the last thing you download. Without it, you can't reliably determine where the individual file records are located in your ZIP file.

This would also explain why DotNetZip needs a seekable stream. It needs to be able to read the Central Directory Record at the end of the file first, then jump back to earlier sections to read information about individual ZIP entries to extract them.

If you have very specific ZIP files you could make certain assumptions about the layout of those individual file records and extract them by hand, without seeking backwards, but it would not be broadly compatible with ZIP files in general.

Comment: Seems like this is the case. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a async Task to unzip

```
await Task.Run(() => ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(localPath + @"\" + fileName, destinationPath));
```

Comment: The underlying problem is whether the zip library will act properly if given an incomplete data source, i.e. wait for missing data or crash out. From what I've tried so far, DotNetZip at least will produced corrupted output or crash if given an incomplete data source

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unpack the vast majority of zipfiles, they contain only file records followed by compressed data, repeated until you hit the central directory. So it is very much possible to do streaming decompression like asked in this question. The fflate JavaScript library does it for example.

It is possible to create a) a self executing zipfile, or b) some other weird ass zipfile that isn't formatted like this, but you'd be hard pressed to find one in the wild.